# Apache only runs my page as PHP if php.ini is missing

Tags: php, windows, apache

I'm trying to make Apache 2.4 work with PHP 5.6 on Windows 8.1.

I added the usual lines to httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
PHPIniDir "c:/php"
```

And it works, displaying phpinfo properly on my test.php page (which is just `Hello! <? phpinfo(); ?>`)... **if** php.ini doesn't exist in c:\php.  (Presumably PHP is using a default configuration, which I need to change to include mysql.)  Once I create php.ini, Apache fails to execute the PHP function, instead just displaying the page as text.

The Apache server doesn't seem to think anything is wrong; on restarting httpd, error.log just displays

```
AH00455: Apache/2.4.10 (Win64) PHP/5.6.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

php.ini is just the php.ini-production file included with the install, renamed.  If I introduce errors into it on purpose, they show up in the Apache log.

What could be causing Apache to not run my page as a PHP file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out: PHP defaults to short_open_tag=On, so my test worked with no config file.  But the default php.ini files have short_open_tag=Off, so my test.php was incorrect: it should have been `Hello! <?php phpinfo(); ?>`).